# Use PopulateObject to populate a List without duplicating entries

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an application that serializes a list of objects to json, then sends this over a socket connection to a client.

On the client side, I'm using JsonConvert.PopulateObject() to populate an existing list of objects with the newly received json data.  However, the objects are continually being appended to the list instead of reusing the existing objects in the list if there are any duplicates.

Here is the class I'm serializing/deserializing:

```
public class Process : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public Process() { }

    public Process(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the PopulateObject code I'm using:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects, ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto };
ObservableCollection<Process> Processes = new ObservableCollection<Process>();
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(response, Processes, settings);
```

It seems like json.net just doesn't know an object is a duplicate reference despite the property values being exactly the same.  I've tried multiple combinations of the JsonObject attribute on my class (IsReference = true, Id = "ID"), etc.  I cannot seem to get json to recognize two objects are the same if their ID property is matching.

Comment: Are you also using the `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` setting on the client side when serializing the data?  This is needed if you want to preserve the references -- it works by writing special `$id` and `$ref` properties into the JSON to help on deserialization.  See @Plutonix's answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not what `PreserveReferencesHandling` does.  It is used to avoid serializing duplicate objects, effectively shortening the json result.  Example:

```
List<NameValuePair> nvpList = new List<NameValuePair>();

NameValuePair z = new NameValuePair(Name="Ziggy", Value= 42);
nvpList.Add(z);
nvpList.Add(new NameValuePair("Zoey", 3));
nvpList.Add(z);

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { 
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects, 
                };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nvpList, Formatting.Indented,
               settings);
```

My `List` has 2 Ziggy objects, but the resulting json is:

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "Name": "Ziggy",
    "Value": 42
  },
  {
    "$id": "2",
    "Name": "Zoey",
    "Value": 3
  },
  {
    "$ref": "1"
  }
]
```

It assigns an internal `$Id` and then references that for the duplicate object.  This only applies where the object references are the same.  If 2 Ziggy objects had been created and added - even with the same values - the json would reflect that and duplicate them.

To prevent duplicates in the list when deserializing, you will have to use a mapper or the equivalent code:

```
List<NameValuePair> tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NameValuePair>>(json);

foreach (NameValuePair nvp in tmp)
{
    if (nvpList.Where(w => w.Value == nvp.Value).FirstOrDefault() == null)
    {
        nvpList.Add(nvp);
    }
}
```

This adds just those where the Value/Id does not already exist in the master list, add whatever logic you need to detect dupes.

See: [Preserving Object References](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/preserveobjectreferences.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried overriding the Equals() function of the serilized object

```
public override bool Equals(Process p)
{
    // If parameter is null return false:
    if ((object)p == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match:
    return (ID == p.ID);
}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this and it looks like it does not help.  I'm not sure if Json.net uses the Equals method to determine equality.

Comment: Have you tried this setting ObjectCreationHandling.Reuse in the JsonSerializerSettings?

Comment: Yep, I've tried that as well and there was no change.  I'm starting to think that maybe there's an attribute I can use to designate the "ID" property as a unique identifier.  But like I said, none of the attributes I've tried have any effect.